# Javascript - ReactJS - display image with ReadableStream as source

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs

I have PNG image as ReadableStream and I need to display html element img with this ReadableStream as source. Should I convert it to something? Or how can I do it?

Thank you for answer

Comment: you can convert png image to base64 and you can use it in img element and display.

Answer (score 6):

From Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api#example_fetching_images):

1. Get response's `blob`
2. Resolve its `Promise`
3. Create a local source with `URL.createObjectURL`
4. Add it to your document (or update state)

Here's an example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


function validateResponse(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

export default class componentName extends Component {

    state = {
        src: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/images/home`)
            .then(validateResponse)
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                this.setState({ src: URL.createObjectURL(blob) })
            })

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.src && <img alt="home" src={ this.state.src }></img> }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my case, data comes from a **`send_file` response from a `Flask` Python backend**